# Linked List Null in C

Tags: c, linked-list

i dont know why the list returned is `NULL`, this is the code:

In my List.h

```
struct nodo_ {
    char* dato;

    struct nodo_ *next;
};
struct nodo_ *Lista;
/*Def list */
void createList(struct nodo_ **Lista);
```

in my main.c

```
struct nodo_ *Lista;

int main(){
    createList(Lista);
    while(Lista != NULL){        
         printf("The date is %s\n  ",Lista->dato); //Error here now
         Lisa = Lista->next;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

in my List.c im create the List :

```
void createList(struct nodo_ *Lista){
    struct nodo_ *Aux_List = list_D;
    aux_List = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo_));

    char* path_a = "Hello"; 
    char* path_B = "Minasan";

    /* Store */
    aux_List->dato = path_a;
    aux_List = Aux_List->next;    
    aux_List = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo_));
    aux_List->dato = path_b;
    aux_List->next = NULL;

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: this shouldnt compile. you have `auxList` and then use `aux_List` with an underscore

Comment: please stop changing your obviously non-compilable code into _slightly different_ non-compilable code and just post what you actually have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That pointer is being passed by value, i.e., a copy is made.  If you wish to initialize the pointer to a completely new value then you must use another level of indirection (i.e., a `nodo_**`).

On a side note, `typedef`ing pointer types is almost always a bad idea unless the type is truly opaque (which yours is not).  One reason for this "rule" is evident when you consider another bug in your code:

```
auxList = (Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
```

You're allocating space for a pointer to `noda_`, not enough for a `noda_` object.  Also, don't cast the return value of `malloc` in C.  It is redundant as a `void*` is safely and implicitly converted to any other pointer type and, if you forget to include `stdlib.h`,  `malloc` will be assumed to be a function which returns `int`, and the cast hides the error. (only applies to compilers which implement C89 or an older version)

EDIT:

To initialize a pointer argument within a function:

```
void init(struct node **n) {
    if(n)
        *n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}

int main() {
    struct node *n;
    init(&n);
}
```

Comment: auxList = (struct nodo_*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo_)); Now i dont have Warning Ty. But i dont understand how can initialize the pointer with another level of indirection.

Comment: @user1558736: So first, remove that cast.  Your initialization function must take a `_nodo**`, i.e., a pointer to pointer to `_nodo`.  Then... `*ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo_))`;

Comment: I would add that `list_D` is a global unintialised variable and as such is placed in the BSS section, which is set to all zeros as the OS creates the process. That's why the initial value of `list_D` is `NULL` and passing it by value to `createList` doesn't change it.

Comment: Fixed malloc , i cant understand how to use _nodo** .. any can give me an example?

Comment: @user1558736: I did in the comment... but I can post a more full example.

Comment: The struct is : struct node{ char*dato; struct node *sig;}; struct node **n; ?

Comment: @user1558736: I added an example.  Also, please read the later part of my response.  Typedefs for non-opaque pointer types are a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to your actual question before I dig into the code:

> ... why the list returned is NULL ...

There *is* no returned list, you neither use `return` to pass a result, nor set the value of an out parameter.

In your edited code:

```
void createList(struct nodo_ **Lista){
    struct nodo_ *Aux_List = list_D;
    aux_List = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo_));
```

you first set `Aux_List` to the *current value* of `Lista`, which you know isn't initialized yet, because you're trying to initialize it. Then you *discard* that value, overwriting `aux_List` with a new address returned by `malloc`. You never store anything into `*Lista`, which would be the only way for this function to work as declared.

---

As Ed suggests, your typedef is hiding lots of useful information from you, so let's expand it out

```
struct nodo {
    char* dato;

    struct nodo *next;
};

/*Def list */
void createList(struct nodo* list_D);
```

Now, you can see this `createList` is wrong: you can pass in the head node of a list (which is no use to it anyway), but there is no way for it to return a newly-allocated list to the caller.

Frankly your `createList` isn't a useful primitive anyway, so I'm going to start with a sensible foundation first:

```
struct nodo *alloc_nodo(char *dato, struct nodo *next)
{
    struct nodo *n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
    n->dato = dato;
    n->next = next;
    return n;
}
```

Now, before we re-write your `createList` using this, let's see what it does now:

```
void createList(struct nodo *list_D)
{
    struct nodo *aux_List = list_D;
    aux_List = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo_));
    /* ^ so, we take the input argument and immediately discard it */

    char* path_a = "Hello"; 
    char* path_B = "Minasan";

    /* Store */
    aux_List->dato = path_a;
    aux_List = Aux_List->next;
    /* ^ note that we haven't initialized aux_List->next yet,
       so this is a random pointer value */

    aux_List = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo_));
    /* again, we set aux_List to something,
       but immediately overwrite and discard it */

    aux_List->dato = path_b;
    aux_List->next = NULL;
}
```

So, it ignores its input, returns no output, and leaks two partially-initialized nodes which aren't connected to each other. I believe you wanted to achieve something more like this:

```
struct nodo* create_my_list()
{
    struct nodo *tail = alloc_nodo("Minasan", NULL);
    /* the end (tail) of the linked list has a NULL next pointer */

    struct nodo *head = alloc_nodo("Hello", tail);
    /* the head of the linked list points to the next node */

    return head;
    /* like a snake, you hold a singly-linked list by the head */
}
```

If we write `main` to use this function now, it looks like:

```
int main()
{
    struct nodo *head = create_my_list();
    struct nodo *n;
    for (n = head; n != NULL; n = n->next)
    {
         printf("The date is %s\n  ", n->dato);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do : printf("%s",Lista->dato) in main; Segmentation fault

Comment: I'm trying to tell you that you _never correctly initialized_ wither `Lista` _or_ `Aux_List`. That's why, when you examine the contents of a variable, you find it has not been initialized. And, when you dereference an uninitialized pointer, you're likely to crash.